# How do you access classes and interfaces from JavaFX in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, javafx

I've never had to use JavaFX in Android Studio before, until now. I need to use the ObservableList interface to monitor changes in ArrayList to perform some action. Unfortunately, when I try to use ObservbaleList, it doesn't appear on the suggested list, and when I try to use anything with JavaFX, I don't have access to it. I can't import anything from JavaFx. I understand that I need to add some classes and interfaces to Android Studio somehow. How could I do this to be able to use all classes and interfaces with JavaFX

Comment: Does it require the Whole javaFX Library, just for the observable List ? Wich JDK are you using? or do you just need any observable list, for updates and callbacks ?

Comment: I would like to have access to the entire library - it may be useful for the future, I use JDK 1.8.0

Comment: Gluon mobile allows you work with JavaFX, least partially. Note that there are some classes that simply are not provided by android; for some classes this doesn't make sense. Swing is another example of an API not available in Android. Android uses a different GUI API so including those classes doesn't make sense...